# renewcommand in a new environment

Tags: enumitem

I have created this environment for a set of exercises at the end of each chapter of a book:

```
\newenvironment{questions}  %Allows problems to be referenced as Problem 10.6 (Ch 10, pr 6)
  {\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\thechapter.\arabic{enumi}}%
   \begin{enumerate}}
  {\end{enumerate}}
```

I tested the use of `\subsubsection*` to separate problems by the section number to which they belong.  Thus I need to issue an \end{questions} command before each `\subsubsection*`, and a `\begin{questions}` command right after.  This in turn requires issuing a `\setcounter{enumi}{num}` command each time, so that the numbering is consecutive throughout the chapter (for example, there are 3 problems in Section 6.1, so section 6.2 starts with problem 6.4).  So far so good.

However, when a problem is \ref’d in the text, the renumbering doesn’t show.  Thus the first problem of Section 6.2 is referred to as Problem 6.1 instead of Problem 6.4.

I can remedy this by repeating

```
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\thechapter.\arabic{enumi}}
```

each time I `\begin{questions}`.  So I do have a fix.

But my question is:  Isn’t there a global way to make this happen?  I’m repeating this `\renewcommand` even though it’s already in the definition of the questions environment.  Seems like a lot of duplication.

Comment: What about using the `enumitem` package?

Comment: with `enumitem` package you can use `resume` option: `\begin{enumerate}[resume]`. see documentation, page 6